# Quel est le sens du mot "cicile"?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, histoire

Dans le livre *Histoire des Croisades* par M. Michaud j'ai trouvé le passage suivant:

> Une vieille relation conservée par un moine de Redon, nous apprend qu'un seigneur puissant du duché de Bretagne, nommé Frotmont, meurtrier de son oncle et du plus jeune de ses frères, se présenta en habit de pénitent devant le roi de France et une assemblée d'évêques. Le monarque et les prélats, après l'avoir fait lier étroitement avec des chaînes de fer, lui ordonnèrent, en expiation du sang qu'il avait versé, de partir pour l'Orient et de parcourir les saints lieux, le front marqué de cendre et le corps couvert d'un *cicile*.

Vous trouvez le lien exact [ici, page 59](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k294192). Je comprends tous les mots dans ce texte sauf *cicile*. Je ne peux pas trouver ce mot dans le Wiktionnaire français et Google ne me donne pas de résultats raisonnables. Alors, je demande ici: quel est le sens du mot *cicile*?

Peut-être qu'un expert ou une experte peut m'aider avec une description ou une traduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

J'imagine que c'est une coquille, et que le mot recherché est plutôt **cilice**.

Cette [définition du Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cilice) qui correspond plutôt bien au contexte:

> Espèce de plastron ou de large ceinture, qui est faite d’un tissu de poil de chèvre, de crin de cheval, ou de quelque autre poil rude et piquant, et que l’on porte sur la chair par mortification.

On trouve d'ailleurs le terme **cilice** [plusieurs fois](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k294192.image.r=cilice.f61) plus loin dans le même document.